Show/Debug Normals from an "Object Info" node - use those normals as input for a displacement GN network
Is it possible, in a Geometry Nodes network, to retrieve the normals from
a given Geometry "Object" different from the Geometry that holds the GN modifier.
Currently, I have made a "switcher" to allow a GN select the input geometry. But for the network to work, I need the computed normals of the modified geometry.
The Normals node used as input to a displacer network doesnt hold the "active", "current" normals data, but the one that belongs to the geometry used as input the group input.
Would it be possible to put an input socket to the Normals node to select the geometry?

Regarding @Crantisz Answer: Yeah, I understand how it works and why it reads the data from the "group input" or geometry data it is connected to. The thing is, I'm trying to build up a scene "piece by piece" and one of them is the possibility to export the GN network and plug it in a dynamically selected mesh/primitive. The GN modifier is attached to a "dummy" geo that means "nothing". It would be extremely helpful in terms of modularity, to be able to plug in "any" mesh and compute the Normals according to this arbitrary mesh and not the one the modifier is applied to. Just wondering if there is a way to do this, or even, good to know if this functionality is planned for the future. In terms of modularity it helps a lot. One could mark "as Asset" the GN object and reuse it. It could be "as easy" as adding an input geometry socket to a "Compute Normals" node and have this node let you select between "Vertex Normal", "Face Normal", "Corner Normal".

Think of the "Normal" node as a function. It reads a normal from current context. What is current context? It depends, unfortunately GN design doesn't make it clear: the context is passed by another function that has called this function, e.g. a "Vector Math" node, that is connected to this node, asks this "Normal" node for data by calling the function Normal(ctx). But where does the "Vec Math" node get the ctx from? Well from yet another node... Most nodes that actually modify context are green and they set ctx to an element of iterated geometry, e.g. "Set Position" iterates over points

The Normals node does not store the normals of the "active" object, instead it derives normals vectors from the data it is connected to
In this example Viewer node shows different normals, then it is connected to different nodes: Cube, Grid and Group input (with Suzanne inside)

Also it may change depends on domain:
Vertex normals:

Face Normals:

See also:
Fields

very interesting @Crantisz the "Fields" concept. Need to read it more carefully.
